# How do I go about calling multiple images of the same group from SQL via PHP

Tags: php, sql

---

**POST EDIT:**

Thanks to a combination of drtechno's code snippet, major assistance from ADyson and Jhecht I figured it out. I was being stupid and without them I wouldn't have understood why.

Here is the code now

```
<?php
  require_once("php/connect.php");
  require_once('php/db.php');
  $contID = $_GET['contentID'];
  $sql = "SELECT imageURL,altText FROM images WHERE imageGroup='$contID' ";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ("Bad Query: $sql");
?>
```

Coupled with drtechno's code snippet

```
<?php
 echo'<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">';
 echo '<div class="carousel-inner">';
 $a=0;

  while ($l = $result->fetch_row()) {
  // on the first one, make active first, then others fallow
   if ($a=="0"){
      echo '<div class="carousel-item active">';
      }else{
      echo '<div class="carousel-item">';
      }

   for ($cont=0; $cont<$result->field_count; $cont++) {
     if ($cont=="0"){
      $dbimg="";
     // now we shift our 1st column data into a temporary variable
       $dbimg=$l[$cont];
        }else{
          // load the 1 column variable, while getting the 2nd
        echo '<img src="'.$dbimg.'" alt="'.$l[$cont].'">';
        }
      }
      echo '</div>';
     $a=$a+1;
     }
   echo '
    </div>
   </div>';
  ?>
```

Both the above snippets are in the article.php template page and I also have a db.php include which is getting the contentID for me to pass to $contID. That's below

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['contentID'])){
    require_once('connect.php');
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['contentID']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE contentID='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ("Bad Query: $sql");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  }else {header('Location: index.php');}

?>
```

Thanks again and I hope this helps someone else too.

---

**PRE-EDIT:**

As the title states I'm trying to call multiple images from an sql database via php. 
I need to have grouped images which fill a BootStrap (BS) carousel related to the article page.

**i.e** I have 12 articles each when clicked opens an article/page with php paginated data, these pages should each contain 3 (different) images which should be displayed in a BS carousel. So a total of 12 image groups with each group having 3 images.

So far I've only managed to do this using multiple SQL queries and it looks messy and long winded.

The quires are as follows

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');
require_once("connect.php");

$img1Result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT imageRef FROM images WHERE imageID = 1 AND contentID = 1");
$img2Result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT imageRef FROM images WHERE imageID = 2 AND contentID = 1");
$img3Result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT imageRef FROM images WHERE imageID = 3 AND contentID = 1");
$img4Result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT imageRef FROM images WHERE imageID = 4 AND contentID = 2");
$img5Result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT imageRef FROM images WHERE imageID = 5 AND contentID = 2");
$img6Result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT imageRef FROM images WHERE imageID = 6 AND contentID = 2");

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ("Bad Query: $sql");
?>
```

and I get the data using the following

```
if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'article.php?contentID=1'){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($img1Result)){
  echo "
  <div class='carousel-item active'>
    <img src='{$row['imageRef']}' class='img-responsive' alt='alt'>
  </div>";
  }
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($img2Result)){
  echo "
  <div class='carousel-item'>
    <img src='{$row['imageRef']}' class='img-responsive' alt='alt'>
  </div>";
  }

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($img3Result)){
  echo "
  <div class='carousel-item'>
    <img src='{$row['imageRef']}' class='img-responsive' alt='alt'>
  </div>";
  }
}
```

The `if` statement checks to see which page has been created when clicking from a link on a previous page and loads the images related to that article.

---

I have also tried (but have limited knowledge with) using joins like so

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');
require_once("connect.php");
  $sql = "SELECT content.contentID,content.title,content.description, images.imageURL, images.imageGroup, images.altText
          FROM content
          INNER JOIN images ON content.contentID=images.imageGroup
          ";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ("Bad Query: $sql");
?>
```

but have no idea how I would make the calls to access the grouped images for each individual article.

My current iteration Uses 3 tables: users, contents and images, see screen shots below.

[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrLD8.jpg)

[content table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68LKi.jpg)

[images table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBIHl.jpg)

The screen shot for the images table only has 2 groups at the moment but this will grow to 12, I've just included as a visual aid.

---

Any help would be appreciated and if the answer is RTFM can you please provide me with either a link to the relevant knowledge source and/or explain to me what it is I'm actually trying to do as I'm really not sure. I also struggle to learn using source documentation and as a noob I find that I learn faster if I'm talked through the problem/solution.

Ideally (and hopefully) someone out there will be Godly enough to provide code examples and explanations to help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Twisted

Comment: for the users table, in production please make sure you are hashing passwords.

Comment: You mean you want all the images for a specific content ID? If so then `$img2Result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT imageRef FROM images WHERE contentID = 1`. This would produce several rows in the results. You can use a loop to go through them. But your code right now also asks for contentID 2 in the same set of queries. Why do you need both of them? It's unclear. Is there a pattern?

Comment: @Jhecht I have it doing so on the live db, this example is using localhost at the moment so didn't think I had much need to salt it.

Comment: Your local should reflect production as much as possible, so I'd recommend hashing stuff in development as well, but obviously that's your choice. Can you give us a quick description of foreign key assignments? Not seeing how those tables are relating to each other.

Comment: @ADyson I think so, basically the contentID is what I'm using to find the imageGroup in the images table (I think). Then for example, if the contentID is 1 (the suffix url for article 1) all images with an imageGroup of 1 show in the carousel, if the contentID is 2 then it would call the imageGroup 2 images to the carousel

Comment: @Jhecht Thanks and good point, I'll keep that in mind in the future. I don't think I have any foreign keys created in phpMyAdmin, I thought they were created with the JOIN INNER bit. Like I said I'm pretty noob, sorry

Comment: So content ID is mapped to imageGroupID in the images table, is that right? Based on your screenshots, your current queries should not even work because the field name is wrong. Are you sure that's your real code?

Comment: You are going to want to grab the value for the `$_GET['contentID']` and then use prepared statements to grab the rows. I don't have PHP installed on my machine, so I don't want to write code that I can't guarantee will work.

Comment: @ADyson the top version of the code uses a different database, sorry for the confusion. I have a ver 1 and ver 2 database which I used to practice setting up databases, I should have used the same naming convention for both dbs but didn't. The first 2 blocks of code I posted relate to the ver 1 db and the 2nd block (the one with the JOIN) and screen shots relate to ver 2.

Comment: @Jhecht. Thanks, I'll look into prepared statements as my next port of call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I have it up top in the POST EDIT bit but I'll put it here as an answer rather than as part of the question I originally asked.

---

Again thanks to a combination of drtechno's code snippet,and some major assistance from ADyson and Jhecht, I figured it out. I was being stupid and without them I wouldn't have understood why.

Here is the code now

```
<?php
  require_once("php/connect.php");
  require_once('php/db.php');
  $contID = $_GET['contentID'];
  $sql = "SELECT imageURL,altText FROM images WHERE imageGroup='$contID' ";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ("Bad Query: $sql");
?>
```

Coupled with drtechno's code snippet

```
<?php
 echo'<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">';
 echo '<div class="carousel-inner">';
 $a=0;

  while ($l = $result->fetch_row()) {
  // on the first one, make active first, then others fallow
   if ($a=="0"){
      echo '<div class="carousel-item active">';
      }else{
      echo '<div class="carousel-item">';
      }

   for ($cont=0; $cont<$result->field_count; $cont++) {
     if ($cont=="0"){
      $dbimg="";
     // now we shift our 1st column data into a temporary variable
       $dbimg=$l[$cont];
        }else{
          // load the 1 column variable, while getting the 2nd
        echo '<img src="'.$dbimg.'" alt="'.$l[$cont].'">';
        }
      }
      echo '</div>';
     $a=$a+1;
     }
   echo '
    </div>
   </div>';
  ?>
```

Both the above snippets are in the article.php template page and I also have a db.php include at the top of the article.php which is getting the contentID for me to pass to $contID. That's below

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['contentID'])){
    require_once('connect.php');
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['contentID']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE contentID='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ("Bad Query: $sql");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  }else {header('Location: index.php');}

?>
```

Thanks again and I hope this helps someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Well its forming your queries, it seems like you need help with.

so lets look at the images table, you have a column for identifying witch ones are and the alt text to put into your img tag.

so like if you stucture your pages like article1.php, article2.php.. etc from your index.html page, you could just call the group of pictures for that article.

Like so:

```
  $img1qry = "SELECT imageURL,altText FROM images WHERE imageGroup = 1";
  $result = $con->query($img1qry)or die (mysqli_error($con));
```

Now, instead of getting each individual out one by one, we loop our output since now we have more objects and we build the carousel as the output from the database returns using a floating variable to control the carousel object build. 
Like so:

```
<?php
 echo'<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">';
 echo '<div class="carousel-inner">';
 $a=0;

  while ($l = $result->fetch_row()) {
  // on the first one, make active first, then others fallow
   if ($a=="0"){
      echo '<div class="carousel-item active">';
      }else{
      echo '<div class="carousel-item">';
      }

 for ($c=0; $c<$result->field_count; $c++) {
   if ($c=="0"){
    $dbimg="";
   // now we shift our 1st column data into a temporary variable
     $dbimg=$l[$c];
    }else{
   // load the 1 column variable, while getting the 2nd
    echo '<img src="'.$dbimg.'" alt="'.$l[$c].'">';
    }
    }
      echo '</div>'; 
     $a=$a+1;
     }
   echo '</div></div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So using this would I still need to SELECT each query (img1qry, img2qry etc) as I have in the 1st code block? 

Also my article page urls are generated and paginated via php using 

`<a href='article.php?contentID={$row['contentID']}'>Click for more info</a>`
which uses the content table.

Comment: @Twisted _"So using this would I still need to SELECT each query (img1qry, img2qry etc) as I have in the 1st code block_" ...no, because `SELECT imageURL,altText FROM images WHERE imageGroup = 1` will return several rows, and `while ($l = $result->fetch_row())` will loop round repeatedly until it uses up all the rows in the result set.

Comment: @ADyson. Cheers for the explanation. How would I then check it against the article.php?contentID=2 and so on up to 12. So for example: I click my link to go to article 2 ( which adds the url suffix of ?contentID=2 ) and only the images from imageGroup 2 appear, and so on up to article 12 and imageGroup 12. Currently regardless of which article page/url I visit I only see the images from imageGroup 1.

And to everyone. Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: @Twisted for that, refer to JHecht's comment on the main thread, above. If you need more detail about using parameters and prepared statements there is a lot of info available online. If you get stuck implementating that then update your question with your attempt